# Update to Apache 2.4 Missing Modules?

Tags: apache-2.4

I have just updated to Apache 2.4 and have been hit by a massive wave of now missing modules, presumably they have been set to disabled by default.

I have been getting errors in the format `Invalid command 'NAME', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration` then Googling what provides that and including the module.

However the one below has me stumped, what have I missed?

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: [Mon May 07 14:42:22.523264 2012] [core:warn] [pid 30648:tid 3082909440]
AH00117: Ignoring deprecated use of DefaultType in line 81 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf/ips.conf:6
AH00526: Syntax error on line 27 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-deflate.conf:
Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The module section at the top of my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule authz_core_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule filter_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_mime.so
LoadModule unixd_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule authz_host_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule access_compat_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule env_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_env.so
LoadModule alias_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule autoindex_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule log_config_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_user_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule dav_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module /usr/lib/apache/mod_dav_lock.so
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There are a tonne of changes from 2.2 to 2.4, modules have changed a lot. Also, many 3rd party modules are incompatible with 2.4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot blindly use an apache 2.2 configuration file with apache 2.4 !

For one, module names have changed, and been added/removed, and for another, the configuration syntax has undergone some (incompatibel) changes.

Refer to the [official 2.4 documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/).

Also note that you will have to re-install/rebuild any and all 3rd-party modules, since apache modules must be built for the specific server they will be used with (most notably, mod_php requires a new package.)

Your specific question regarding the Header directive:

```
Loadmodule header_module /path/to/mod_header.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrade to FC 18 (httpd-2.4.3) from FC 17 (httpd-2.2x)

I have solved it by commenting out all incompatible directives described on:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

I have added string to file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
```

after

```
KeepAliveTimeout 5
```

and before

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
```

Also, I have added directives:

```
<IfModule mod_unixd.c>
User apache
Group apache
</IfModule>
```

under all commented # LoadModule directives

Comment: Per the other answer, you can't use 2.2 config, which is what I'm assuming you're including.